# How do I export my scene with the propper nodes to a Collada file from my cycles render

Tags: rendering, materials, export

How do I export my scene with the propper nodes to a Collada file from my cycles render

I am working on a spaceshipe but when i try to export it to a collada file the texteres are missing, I am using the cycles render and the textures are no images.